# Get the list of the default system variables

Tags: powershell

How can I get the list of all the default system variables (automatic variables) when you fresh open Powershell or when open a new tab?

```
ConfirmPreference
ConsoleFileName
DebugPreference
etc.
```

I am not talking about Get-Variable to receive all the variables, I just want the default ones.

For example an idea like :

```
[System.Management.Automation.PSVariable]::GetVariable
```

Comment: Curious as to why since the list is already published? `Get-Variable *` at the start of the session would have them..... I know you said you didnt want that but they are there.

Comment: Yes I know this solution but it is not the way I want this information ... I want a more "cleaner / technical" way.

Comment: I hope someone else has what you are looking for but I am not sure what you will get that is more_cleaner / technical_ then just `GV `. Saving the results in the beginning then doing a diff as you go along. Opening a new session and tab are different things which is why I mention the diff option. I have not found a property the variables all share.

Comment: Inconvenient is that if you use a profile with tons of variables, environment get "polluated" and hard to get the real fresh list without starting with no profile.

Comment: My question would be rather "How are the automatic variables generated at the startup?"

Answer (score 0):

Just capture all the variables as the first action in your profile.  Something like this:

```
Get-variable * > Autovars.txt
Get-variable * | Export-csv Autovars.csv
```

That way you'll get the variables that exist before the rest of your profile runs.  The second command captures more of the properties of each variable  So later on, you could retrieve the data as follows:

```
type Autovars.txt
Import-csv Autovars.csv | ft
```

If you mean something different by "more technical", then you'll just have to explain what you are looking for.